# Change base url depending of node field value

Tags: multi-sites, uri

There is a multi-site (2 sub domains) running Drupal 7. Each node has a field where I set the site this node has to be shown on. It is also an option to show the node on both sites. For SEO reasons I have to keep those on parent domain. So actually there are 3 sites.

On both sites there is a list of available nodes. In the sub1.site.com it consists of nodes marked 'for sub1' and 'for all'. In the sub2.site.com - of nodes markef 'for sub2' and 'for all' accordingly.

So when Drupal is collecting titles for show it has to make a proper url (actually a proper base url) for each node. That's the task.

I know how to make it for a certain page or pages one by one, but I feel it's better to make it in some global way. But I'm confused where exactly (and also how exactly) it would be the best.

Suggestions of any kind would be appreciated.